# Elasticsearch must and must_not not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run a query as shown below:

```
query = {
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must_not": [{"term":{"text":"exclude_word"}}],
        "must": [{"term":{"text":"include_word"}}]
      }
    },
    "query": {
      "dis_max": {
        "queries": [
          {"match": {"text": "search_term"}},
          {"match": {"title": "search_term"}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
}
client.search(
{
  index: 'docs',
  body: {
      from: start_page,
      size: 10,
      query: query,
      highlight : {
        fields : {
          text : {
          }
        }
      }
  })
```

The purpose of this query is to search through all documents for the "search_term" and exclude documents which contain "exclude_word" and don't contain "include_word" in their text field.

My problem is that it doesn't seem to filter out the documents containing the exclude_word. Assume that "start_page" is a variable I'm updating and its working fine alongside a paging front end.

My text field is analyzed and its in the following format:

```
"text": ["sentence 1", "sentence 2", "sentence 3"]
```

Also the client.search part is just an API for node.js that I'm using and it works fine and can be ignored.

Comment: `term` query is meant for exact matches only. As `text` is an analyzed string, you most likely want to use `match` instead.

Comment: changed that but still no different from the results I was getting before. I'm checking for just a single word so I thought it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `explain` API? It will walk through the query and _explain_ why something did or did not match. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-explain.html

Comment: It is strange, I have created a small sample myself that seems to be working fine. Cannot spot a problem in your code. Maybe create a sample data set in elastic sense and check the query there? Easier for us to look at what you are doing at try it ourselves.